# "Favour" or "favor"

Tags: ambiguity

Are the terms *favour* and *favor* interchangeable ? Or is there a slight difference perhaps? This is nitpicking but just curious.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/info/spelling-reform.htm there are other words like this : *defence* and *defense* . Why do we have different American and British versions? How did they come to existence? What purpose do they serve?

Comment: [Favour](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/favour?q=favour) is the regular spelling. It's *favor* in the US.

Comment: "Regular spelling"? From my vantage point, it's the other way around.

Comment: You can thank [Noah Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/info/spelling-reform.htm) for that.

Comment: ELU does not underline anything: I would guess your browser, being set to English, thinks the American word a misspelling.

Comment: @TimLymington I knew that , just wanted to know was it Elu or something else

Comment: @Laure What about ce vs se?

Comment: [“Defense” or “defence”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15895/defense-or-defence) on en.se. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences) can be helpful as well.

Comment: The whys and hows is a very interesting story, but one that can be researched without EL&U answers. Just google "History of American spelling" or similar.

Comment: Like I knew , it was duplicate...how could have I known...your Elu algorithms did not show me this option , not my fault .i don't even care for the question ,just wanted to see if someone could answer such a question.

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference between the two. *Favour* is the spelling used in the UK and other Commonwealth countries, while *favor* is the spelling used in the United States.

Comment: And applies to countless other words ending in ...our; colour, honour, rumour, etc.