# Difference between "offense" and "offence"

Tags: etymology

Between *offense* and *offence*, which one is more correct spelling?

If both are correct, are there any differences in shades of meaning and/or usage?

Comment: Hello Bella. Please don't shout. //  Have you looked in a dictionary or two?

Comment: _Offence_ is a UK spelling, and _offense_ is an American spelling. They refer to the same word, which is pronounced the same and used the same no matter how it's spelled. English spelling is not always consistent (to say the very least), and pairs like _honor/honour_ and _theater/theatre_ are not uncommon.

Answer (score 3):

I found this same question asked 4 years ago. Hope this helps.

[Is there any difference between "offense" and "offence"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16668/is-there-any-difference-between-offense-and-offence)

Comment: Jony, the correct course of action is to flag as a duplicate.

Comment: My bad. I couldn't find the option of flagging it as "duplicate" that time. I, however, have marked it as "in need of moderator intervention" instead. Is that alright?

Comment: Yes, but there's no point now since it's been marked as a duplicate already. However, next time... :-)